# How to manipulate MS Word 2010 document word by word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to develop an MS Word 2010 Add-in (2013/2016 also) which works like a spellchecker (restores accent characters) for Turkish Text. I want to give 3 options (via context menu) to the users to use the tool.

- fix all text in the document. (including the ones in the tables and lists etc.)
- fix all text in a selected area
- fix the word at the cursor position.

For the first option I tried to iterate all the words and fix them one by one by the following code:

```
var words = App.ActiveDocument.Words;

foreach (Range word in words)
{
    var corr = MyCorrecter(word.Text);
    word.Select();
    App.Selection.TypeText(corr);
}
```

However this stuck in an infinite-loop. `word.Next()` always returns the first word. If I remove the line `word.Text = MyCorrecter(word.Text);`, code iterates all the words successfully. There are find/replace examples around but those are not very efficient for this particular case.

In short, what is the most effective way to manipulate words one by one in a Word Document?

Comment: @stuartd The code above, except the `word.Text = MyCorrecter(word.Text);` line, also loops through each word. But when I set a word's text, it doesn't work.

Comment: what kind of "doesn't work" - the text is unchanged, there's an error, or ..?

Comment: @stuartd I edited the question. Please re-read the paragraph right under the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of situation - where you're actually changing the content of the target Range ("word") you need to work with a loop that "counts" with an index. For example:

```
Word.Words words = app.ActiveDocument.Words;
int iWordCount = words.Count;
Word.Range rngWord = null;
for (int i = 1; i<= iWordCount; i++) 
{
  rngWord = words[i]
  var corr = MyCorrecter(rngWord.Text);
  rngWord.Text = corr;
 }
//When you're done, dont' forget to release the COM objects
rngWord = null;
words = null;
```

I strongly recommend you do NOT use Select or Selection in your code unless what you need to do cannot be done any other way. Assign directly to the Range.Text object.

Note that there are situations in Word when it helps to run a loop backwards through the document (going from the highest counter to the lowest). I think this situation will work going forwards, however.

Comment: "I strongly recommend you do NOT use Select or Selection in your code unless what you need to do cannot be done any other way. Assign directly to the Range.Text object." Can elaborate on that?

Comment: Selection tends to be slower in execution. It's not as reliable - the user could click on the document / it may not be where you think it is. At a later point or for someone else it's not clear what the code is doing and where. You can have only one selection In the Word.Application, but multiple ranges.